# Find a function with two variables and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd really appreciate some help with this, given four numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ - how do I work out an equation that will return a value $V$, which when input into an inverse function/equation like so $f(V, x_1, y_1)$ will return the original $x_2$ and $y_2$.

All the numbers range from $0$ - $100$ max and $V$ must fall within this range. Is this even possible? My apologies if this isn't proper math lingo but I haven't seen the inside of a classroom in a few decades. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But it's not pretty.

One way is to interleave the digits of each of the $x_i$ and $y_i$ so that, for instance,
$$\begin{align}
&x_1=33.33333\ldots\\
&x_2=44.44444\ldots\\
&y_1=77.77777\ldots\\
&y_2=88.88888\ldots
\end{align}
$$
gives
$$
V=34.7834783478\ldots
$$
This way you don't even have to feed in $x_1,y_1$ to $f$, you can just extract the four points directly without any worries.

You might need to be a bit careful with the whole $0.999\ldots=1$ thing, though; I haven't checked all possible edge cases.